# Historic state-to-state migration in the US

Tags: usa, historical

A few month ago, I tried to obtain data on [county-to-county migration in the US](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10288/us-county-to-county-migration-flows-historic-data-for-the-20th-century) but realized that this data might be to specific to find. Now I try my luck with a less detailed version:

I am looking for state-to-state migration data for each decade from 1950 to 1990. Ideally, this data would contain separate numbers of migrants moving from, say, California to Arizona and from Arizona to California (but for all state pairs in the US). In absence of that, I could also do with the total number of migration between any two states.

I am looking for separate data sets for 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980 and 1990 and any subset of these is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but related information giving a hint of the average trend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_center_of_the_United_States_population

Comment: Doesn't help me with the data hunt (of course) but the illustration does tell you something! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: *(as user)* I've answered your county question. but data only goes back to 1990. There is also state-to-state migration data available on the same page. http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10733/1511

Comment: *(as mod)* I would suggest editing the county question to include county OR state data. Then we can close this one as duplicate.

Comment: @philshem: that seems fair enough, will edit the other thread.